# Разбираю пример rss новостей, в общем списке дублируется общее название новостей, почему так?

Tags: android, listview, rss

Сначала думала что это проблема rss-ссылки, но такая история со всеми ссылками: 
[image]

```
    public class RssItem {

    private final String title;
    private String description;
    private final String link;
    private int id;
    private byte[] thumbnailBytes;

    public RssItem(String title, String link) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public byte[] getThumbnailBytes() {
        return thumbnailBytes;
    }
    public void setThumbnailBytes(byte[] thumbnailBytes) {
        this.thumbnailBytes = thumbnailBytes;
    }
    public RssItem(int id, String title, String description, String link,
            byte[] imageBytes) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        //this.description = description;
        this.link = link;
        this.id = id;
        this.thumbnailBytes = imageBytes;
    }
}
```

И вот адаптор:

```
    public class RssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<RssItem> items;
    private final Context context;

    public RssAdapter(Context context, List<RssItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTitle;
    }
}
```

RssItem.java:

```
    public class RssItem {

    private final String title;
    private String description;
    private final String link;
    private int id;
    private byte[] thumbnailBytes;

    public RssItem(String title, String link) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public byte[] getThumbnailBytes() {
        return thumbnailBytes;
    }
    public void setThumbnailBytes(byte[] thumbnailBytes) {
        this.thumbnailBytes = thumbnailBytes;
    }
    public RssItem(int id, String title, String description, String link,
            byte[] imageBytes) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.link = link;
        this.id = id;
        this.thumbnailBytes = imageBytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попро6уйте посмотреть что в действительности находится в `List<RssItem>`, может быть двойственность появилась уже там и адаптер тут не причем. Или двойственность появляется при заполнении данного списка.

Так же как вариант можете использовать вместо `List` интерфейс `Set`, который исключает дубликацию, но для этого вам прийдется сначала переопределить методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` у класса `RssItem`.

Comment: RssItem вроде чистенький и логичный (повесила код в тему).

Comment: Вот тут 100% рабочий пример ListView с Holder pattern'ом. Пример 6.4: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Если данные приходят в правильном виде, то скорее всего глюк нужно искать в getView() адаптера.